# Autocomplete TextField Suggestions not registering click event SwiftUI

Tags: autocomplete, swiftui, textfield, buttonclick, swiftui-form

I'm new to SwiftUI (like most of us)

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete TextField with google places, I have the basic implementation working, but my button clicks aren't working on my "suggestions" list.

Code posted below

```
struct CreateVenueView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: CreateVenueViewModel = CreateVenueViewModel()
    @State private var selectedSport = 0 {
        willSet(newValue) {
            print(newValue)
        }
    }


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedSport, label: Text("Sport")) {
                    ForEach(Sport.all()) { sport in
                        Text(sport.value.capitalized)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 5)

                TextField("Venue name", text: $viewModel.venueName)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)

                TextField("Address", text: $viewModel.typedAddress)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)

                TextField("Venue detail", text: $viewModel.selectedSport)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
            }
            if !viewModel.addresses.isEmpty {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.addresses) { address in
                            Button(action: {
                                self.viewModel.selectedAddress = address
                            }) {
                                Text("\(address.displayAddress())")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: CGFloat(viewModel.addresses.count * 50))
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                .offset(y: 120)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(Color.Palette.accent)
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Venue")
    }
}
```

As you can see when there are "addresses" available in my viewmodel we show the suggestion list.  gif attached.

[image: Demo]

However the Button actions aren't invoked for all items, the first two items register clicks as you can see from the highlight when the 2nd option is selected, but when any element is selected underneath the second option, you'll see the interation occurs with the form.

When I don't have the offset or the spacer the list is rendered at the bottom of the screen, well below the form, and all the button actions are invoked.  So I'm guessing there's an issue with the form intercepting the click events as opposed to my suggestion list.

Anyone have an idea what I could do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of a List will a Picker work? I've had trouble with Lists selecting even if I add a Button or tapGesture to the item, but a Picker seems to work for selections.

Answer (score -1):

```
                        List {
                               ForEach(viewModel.addresses) { address in
                                    {
                                        Text("\(address.displayAddress())")
                                          .onTapGesture{
                                             self.viewModel.selectedAddress = address

                                        }
                                      }
                                }
                         }
```

might work.